# Get current working directory in terraform

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I am running Terraform using Terragrunt so I am not actually certain about the path that the terraform is invoked from.

So I am trying to get the current working directory as follows:

```
resource null_resource "pwd" {
  triggers {
    always_run = "${uuid()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo $pwd >> somefile.txt"
  }
}
```

However the resulting file is empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with using `path.cwd` or `path.root` (see https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#references-to-named-values)?

Comment: docs have moved to https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/references.html#filesystem-and-workspace-info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try 
`command = "echo $(pwd) > somefile.txt"`

Comment: a verb description is often helpful

Answer (score 95):

Terraform has a [built-in object `path`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#filesystem-and-workspace-info) that contains attributes for various paths Terraform knows about:

- `path.module` is the directory containing the module where the `path.module` expression is placed.
- `path.root` is the directory containing the root module.
- `path.cwd` is the current working directory.

When writing Terraform modules, we most commonly want to resolve paths relative to *the module itself*, so that it is self-contained and doesn't make any assumptions about or cause impacts to any other modules in the configuration. Therefore `path.module` is most often the right choice, making a module agnostic to where it's being instantiated from.

It's very uncommon to use the current working directory because that would make a Terraform configuration sensitive to where it is applied, and likely cause unnecessary resource changes if you later apply the same configuration from a different directory or on a different machine altogether. However, in the rare situations where such a thing is needed, `path.cwd` will do it.

`path.module` and `path.root` are both relative paths from `path.cwd`, because that minimizes the risk of inadvertently introducing details about the system where Terraform is being run into the configuration. However, if you *do* need an absolute module path for some reason, you can use [`abspath`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/abspath.html), like `abspath(path.module)`.

Comment: crazy when I know what I'm looking for, but I can find it faster in SO than in the official documentation, which I searched first.

Comment: So far humans continue to beat search engines in interpreting broad descriptions of a goal and mapping them to existing solutions, I guess! 

Comment: @MartinAtkins how is your opinion on this in december 2023? ;-)

Comment: @Cloudkollektiv I'd wager a guess at "still pretty confident", since this answer is what GPT-4 and Bing regurgitates nearly word-for-word.